# Where can I find a full list of cities where Uber operates?

Tags: international-travel, online-resources, taxis, domestic-travel, uber

When arranging travel I find myself google 'does X have Uber?' a *lot* (substituting a different city for 'X' each time).

Is there a complete, up-to-date list somewhere?

Comment: Are you arranging travel in advance? If you are in a city and open the Uber app you should be able to see instantly if Uber is available.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler not booking actual rides but getting a feel for which cities will be easily and affordable traversed vs those which may be more involved (language barrier, negotiating prices, tipping, reliability, safety, etc)

Comment: I find this to be a perfectly valid question that I've tried to find an answer to before.

Answer (score 7):

A search on Google would have found you [this page](https://www.uber.com/global/en/cities/). 700 cities listed on the Uber web site.

Answer (score 1):

@Arthur has provided a good base to answer your question. And to be fair, to quickly check if Uber is present in a specific country - it's probably the best and easiest way.

However, for identifying whether Uber is present in a specific location i.e. city, town or a village, I will still advise to actually open the Uber app to see if there are any Uber cars in that location. If the location is not officially in the list that doesn't mean you won't find Uber cars there!

Alternatively to using the Uber app, it seems entering your location on [UberEstimator](https://uberestimator.com/available) provides the same information, not sure how accurate it is but it gave positive result for Milton Keynes in the UK, which is not on the Uber website but is indeed on the Uber app and on UberEstimator website:

[image: Uber in Milton Keynes]